# React event.target.value returns undefined when using react-input-slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, events

I am using the react-input-slider in my codebase currently and am having errors when trying to seek using the slider. It can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-slider

I am using it like this:

```
import Slider from 'react-input-slider';

<Slider
 className="clickable-seek-bar"
 axis="x"
 type="range"
 xmin={0}
 xmax={0.999999}
 xstep={0.1}
 x={this.state.played}
 onDragStart={this.handleSeekMouseDown}
 onDragEnd={this.handleSeekMouseUp}
 onChange={this.handleSeekChange}
/>
```

These are the functions I have:

```
handleSeekMouseDown(e) {
 this.setState({ ...this.state, seeking: true });
}

handleSeekChange(e) {
 this.setState({ ...this.state, played: parseFloat(e.target.value) });
}

handleSeekMouseUp(e) {
 console.log("TEST", e.target.value);
 this.player.seekTo(parseFloat(e.target.value));
 this.setState({ ...this.state, seeking: false });
}
```

Whenever I click on the bar, I get an error saying:

```
(index):33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

I am not sure what is causing this. event.target.value is returning undefined for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass e as a parameter when you call the event handler function.  It'd be something like this

```js
import Slider from 'react-input-slider';

<Slider
 className="clickable-seek-bar"
 axis="x"
 type="range"
 xmin={0}
 xmax={0.999999}
 xstep={0.1}
 x={this.state.played}
 onDragStart={this.handleSeekMouseDown}
 onDragEnd={this.handleSeekMouseUp}
 onChange={ e => this.handleSeekChange(e)}
/>
```

Comment: I made the necessary changes to onDragEnd and onChange but still the error persists.

Comment: Try console logging e and see what's returning